# How to change the type of a field in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I need a function in Typescript that takes an object as argument and assigns a value to a certain property of that object, but the value will have a different type than the original object.

So for example when having an object of type `{x: boolean, y: number}` I want to assign `'Hello World'` to the field `y`, this is offcourse not possible because y is a `number`, but with the help of advanced types I can build a workarround.

```
// Change the type
type ChangeType<Of, To, Where extends keyof Of> = {
    [K in keyof Of]: K extends Where ? To : Of[K]
}
```

Using `ChangeType` I can change the object like this:

```
//                          Of               To    Where
let x: ChangeType<{x: boolean, y: number}, string, 'y'> = { 
    x: true, 
    y: 'Hello World'
}
```

Now I want to generalize this into a generic function, this is what I tried:

```
let change = <T, U, Condition extends keyof T>(entity: T, new_value: U, property: Condition): ChangeType<T, U, Condition> => {
    return {...entity, [property]: new_value}
}
```

But I get the following type error:

> Type 'T & { [x: string]: U; }' is not assignable to type 'ChangeType'.ts(2322)

So how can I change the type of an objects field in a generic way?

Comment: Don't think you will get the implementation to fully type check, just use a type assertion.

Comment: Could have thought about that, I tried casting it to type `any`, but `<ChangeType<T, U, Condition>>{...entity, [property]: new_value}` works for me

Comment: Yea asserting to `ChangeType<T, U, Condition>` should work. TS often has trouble following conditional an mapped types while they still have unresolved type parameters